# thunderbird - cannot create new gmail account - oauth page is hanging

Tags: thunderbird

I am unable to create new gmail accounts in thunderbird.  The oauth page comes up where it asks you for your email address, but clicking any button in there does not do anything.  I am running thunderbird 45.8.0 and checked my firewall logs, but don't see anything.  It is as if the buttons on that page do NOT work.  I can log into gmail.com fine and have enabled IMAP access for the account in question.

I'm trying thunderbird on another machine to see if it is a problem with my version of thunderbird or a configuration setting.  I also tried changing the proxy settings, but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet that this is a problema with Thunderbird version. Take a look at this bug reports on Ubuntu launchpad an Mozilla:

- [Can't login in Gmail account](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1688765)

> I'm trying to login in my gmail account.
>
> After entering email and password I have a Google page with enter
>   point.
>
> But when I press the Continue button - nothing happens.
>
> Screen in attachment.
>
> Test case:
>
> Open Thunderbird and try to login in Gmail account with 2-auth.
>
> 1) Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS x86_64
>
> 2) 1:45.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
>
> 3) Continue authorization in Gmail
>
> 4) Pressing the continue button have no effect

[- Thunderbird 45.8.0 hangs on new Gmail password window](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1364006)

> Steps to reproduce:
>
> Tried to create a new profile with a gmail account in ThB 45.8.0
>
> Actual results:
>
> GMail's Auth page appears, pre-filled with my email address, but
>   clicking on "Next" button has no effect, so the password cannnot be
>   verified, thus the account cannot be created. My problem is exactly
>   the one described here : 
>   https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=244609&p=1314125#p1314125
>   NOTE: my config already says that OAuth2 is selected...
>
> Expected results:
>
> GMail Auth window should work or an alternative way of
>   configuring/verifying the account should be proposed

Both bug reports refers exactly to Thunderbird version 45.8.0. Try a more recent version (like 54) and see if this still happens.